# HTML navigation tabs doesn't work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, nav

Hi I have complication regarding on bootstrap. My code doesn't work is there something wrong? any idea to solve the problem?--thanks

```
<nav id='nav-reservation'>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <a href='resource-index.php?page=room' class='nav-reservation-item <?php if($_REQUEST[' page '] == "room"){ echo "active"; } ?>'>Room</a>
            <a href='resource-index.php?page=equipment' class='nav-reservation-item <?php if($_REQUEST[' page '] == "equipment"){ echo "active"; } ?>'>Equipment </a>
            </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="room" class="tab-pane fade in active"></div>
        <div id="equipment" class="tab-pane fade in active"></div>
     </div>   
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add li tag in ul tag.

```
<nav id='nav-reservation'>
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
       <li> <a href='resource-index.php?page=room' class='nav-reservation-item <?php if($_REQUEST[' page '] == "room"){ echo "active"; } ?>'>Room</a></li>
    <li>    <a href='resource-index.php?page=equipment' class='nav-reservation-item <?php if($_REQUEST[' page '] == "equipment"){ echo "active"; } ?>'>Equipment </a></li>
        </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="room" class="tab-pane fade in active"></div>
    <div id="equipment" class="tab-pane fade in active"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: i tried to add ul tag the nav tab  happen to be in next line :(

Comment: add the snippet of it. @TheJoempossibleDream

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that you have both of your tab content pane's with the `in active` classes on them and the only one that should have these classes is the active open pane.  Having both of these with the `in active` classes will show both of the tabs at the same time.

Next the tabs are activated by a hashtag in the href of the nav tabs.  And you have no hashtag.  They should correspond with the tab pane that you want to open.  So if you want to open the tab with the id `#room` in the href in the nav tabs you should specify this.  Also you should put the `data-toggle="tab"` in the href as well like so:

```
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#room">Room</a>
```

This will open the tab with the id `#room`

So your markup should look something like the following without your custom php:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a  data-toggle="tab" href="#room">Room</a></li>
      <li><a  data-toggle="tab" href="#equipment">Equipment</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="room" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        First Tab
      </div>
      <div id="equipment" class="tab-pane fade">
        Second Tab
      </div>
    </div>
```